# Cannot install MvvmLight for Windows Phone 8.1 app project

Tags: c#, mvvm-light, windows-phone-8.1

I'm trying to install MvvmLight on my Windows Phone 8.1 project (Visual Studio 2013) but keep getting this error message:

> Install-Package : Could not install package 'Portable.MvvmLightLibs 4.4.32.1'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'WindowsPhoneApp,Version=v8.1', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.

The description of the package states:

> The MVVM Light Toolkit is a set of components helping people to get started in the Model-View-ViewModel pattern in Silverlight, WPF, Windows Phone, Windows Store and Xamarin Android. It is a light and pragmatic framework that contains only the essential components needed. This version contains the portable libraries for WPF4.5, Windows 8 and 8.1, **Windows Phone 8.1** and Xamarin Android!

What gives? As background, I previously installed the MVVM Light package (4.2.30.0) and the uninstalled it because it didn't add any references. It kept the View Model locators around.

Comment: First of all, what app is that? Windows Phone RT or Windows Phone 8.1 SilverLight?

Comment: Actually, it is a Windows Phone 8.1 Store App. It appears in new project under Visual C# -> Store Apps -> Windows Phone Apps -> Blank App (Windows Phone). However, Blank App (Windows Phone Silverlight) does not work either, when targeted to 8.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens if you are using an older version of NuGet. Once I updated NuGet, the problem went away.