# How to Install MVVMLight in Xamarin Studio Xamarin.Forms PCL

Tags: mvvm-light, xamarin-studio

I think this is related to this -

[Cannot install MvvmLight for Windows Phone 8.1 app project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24154422/cannot-install-mvvmlight-for-windows-phone-8-1-app-project)

Trying to install libs only nuget.  Seen a PCL version mentioned somewhere but its not in the Nuget list.

> Could not install package 'MvvmLightLibs 4.4.32.1'. You are trying to
>   install this package into a project that targets
>   'portable-net45+win+MonoAndroid10+MonoTouch10', but the package does
>   not contain any assembly references or content files that are
>   compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the
>   package author.

When I try to install in Xamarin Studio.

Can I assume that I need the latest version of NuGet and the version 2.8.1 is not new enough in XS?

Does MVVMLight support Xamarin Studio? Does anyone know a workaround, I am currently on Indie license and would love to progress with this on a Forms based prototype.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the MvvmLightLibs 4.4.32.1 NuGet package it does not have any Portable Class Libraries (PCLs) so you will not be able to install it into a PCL project.

Take a look at the [Portable.MvvmLightLibs](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Portable.MvvmLightLibs/) NuGet package instead. That package has a PCL assembly and you should be able to install it into the Xamarin.Forms PCL project.

Comment: Thanks Matt, I have no idea why that did not show up when searching for "mvvmlight pcl" in the nuget search, it is late!! :)